# How do I unlock the next level in Angry Birds?

Tags: angry-birds

I'm currently playing Version 1.4.4 of Angry birds on. I have managed to get three stars in all sections in Poached Eggs, Mighty Hoax, Danger Above and The Big Setup.  I have 17 golden eggs and stars in all of them.  Now, nothing is happening.

How can I progress to the next bit?

Comment: possibly related to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/how-to-get-the-score-addict-achievement ?

Comment: Version 1.4.4 is specific to iThings ... as written, I think this is an Apple-device question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think any more levels have been released yet.  As the game is updated, more levels will become available, so it looks like you're going to have to wait.

---

**Edit:**
There have been some new levels released - The *"Ham 'em High"* level pack will become available once you update your application.

Comment: yup,v 1.4.4 has 21 levels on chapters 1-5 (sections 1 and 2, or poached eggs and might hoax) and 15 levels on chapters 6-11 (sections 3 and 4, or danger above and the big setup).  So far that's all they've released.

Answer (score 0):

A new "world", Ham 'Em High, has been released.  You need to update the app in order to get these new levels.  And once you beat them, *expect* nothing to happen unless there's another update.  This game has an end :)

**Edit:** Another set of 45 levels, Mine and Dine, has been released, plus the Birthday levels.